# Making version with npm version

Tags: git, jenkins, npm, package.json

When i try the command below:

```
 npm version 0.0.153-publish_nexus.8 --no-git-tag-version
```

i get the following output :

```
npm ERR! npm version [<newversion> | major | minor | patch | premajor | preminor | prepatch | prerelease | from-git]
npm ERR! (run in package dir)
npm ERR! 'npm -v' or 'npm --version' to print npm version (5.10.0)
npm ERR! 'npm view <pkg> version' to view a package's published version
npm ERR! 'npm ls' to inspect current package/dependency versions
```

this is my package.json:

```
{
    "name": "test-version",
    "version": "0.0.153",
    "license": "MIT",
   "files": [
    "dist"
  ]}
```

Any ideas why i get that error ?

Comment: This is just a guess, but npm says for `<newversion>` it uses the [semvar spec](https://semver.org/), which only seems to allow 3 fields (`major.minor.patch`), whereas you have `0.0.153-public_nexus.8` which is 4 fields.

Comment: same error even with that

Comment: i found the error semvar spec doesn't accept the name public_nexus the error was caused by _ when removed it works perfectly